# Failed to collect dependencies from springtestdbunit

Tags: maven, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

I have some issue Dbunit and unable to solve it. The issue is maven unable to collect dependencies form dbunit test. Here is a log error.

Java 7
Maven 3.6.1

`Could not resolve dependencies for project net.tao:DD-sms-delivery-report:jar:1.1: Failed to collect dependencies at com.github.springtestdbunit:spring-test-dbunit:jar:1.3.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.github.springtestdbunit:spring-test-dbunit:jar:1.3.1: Could not transfer artifact com.github.springtestdbunit:spring-test-dbunit:pom:1.3.1 from/to codelds (https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure -> [Help 1]`

and pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <springtest.dbunit.version>1.3.1</springtest.dbunit.version>
        <dbunit.version>2.5.2</dbunit.version>
    </properties>
```

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>${springtest.dbunit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What is the java and maven version you are using?

Comment: Java 7 and maven 3.6.1

Comment: Check out https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html